# How to add a designer property for a collection to my server control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, custom-controls, designer, web-controls

I have a server control and I want to add a property that is a list of objects. I want this property to be configurable through the designer similar to drop down list items etc.

Here is an attempt at defining the property:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Set this if you want to customize the export drop down options
    /// </summary>
    [Description("Customize the export drop down options if you do not want to use the defaults."), DefaultValue(null)]
    [Category("Misc")]
     [DesignerSerializationVisibility(
        DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content),
    Editor(typeof(List<MenuItem>), typeof(UITypeEditor)),
    PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerDefaultProperty)]
    public List<MenuItem> ExportMenuItems
    {
        get { return _ExportMenuItems; }
        set { _ExportMenuItems = value; }
    }
```

Another attempt used MenuItemCollections.

Currently the problem is that when I click on the ellipses button in the Object Properties window when on the designer a window pops up then immediately disappears.

I have looked at these links but I am not sure if this is what I need:

[Web Control Collection Property Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9txe1d4x.aspx)

[Collection Editor Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9zky1t4k.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

if you see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9txe1d4x.aspx) it is defined like that

```
Editor(typeof(ContactCollectionEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor)),...
```

and you have

```
Editor(typeof(List<MenuItem>), typeof(UITypeEditor)),...
```

I don't know if this will help you. I just saw it and wanted to point it out.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9zky1t4k.aspx   ContactCollectionEditor is a custom class that inherits CollectionEditor. So I might need to make a similar class for a collection of MenuItems. Hopefully I can find time to try it out. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. :)